# Measures and filters

Tags: marketing-cloud, error, filters

I'm trying to find who ever got and specific email 3 days ago.

So I made a Measure:

Event source: Sent
Condition: Email name == 2015-11-11_Praeaktiveerede_kort_invitation

I know I have sent 46 mails with this specific name to and Data Extension which my new filter is also based on.

But I'm getting 0 subscribers.

I think maybe my issue is the filter:

[image]

Im not Sure if the `Tempkort - fil mail 1 for 3 dage siden` measure name is greater than or equal to 1 is correct.

I can't find any documentation on this issue.  Should it just be `= 1` or `> 0`?

I'm confused.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the filter we're discussing?

Answer (score 1):

Try "greater than or equal to 0" in the filter for your measure - for some reason that has been much more reliable for me then the ">= 1" which is in documentation.

Comment: I ended up making this filter+measure in Querries instead, using the _Job and _sent tables